# LISP error in FORMAT function call

Tags: output, lisp, common-lisp

I wrote this code to write of a file:

```
(defun writefile (text filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename :direction :output :if-exists :supersede
                   :if-does-not-exist :create)
    (format stream text)))
```

but if i execute, for example:

```
(writefile '(a b c) "foo.txt")
```

returns:

> Error: In a call to FORMAT: (A B C) is not of type (OR STRING
>   FUNCTION).

Why it shows me that error?

Comment: `:if-does-not-exist :create` actually impedes readability, IMHO. This is the standard default behavior when opening a file: seeing that parameter explicitly set to `:create` is kind of confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [`format`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_format.htm) call is wrong:
the second argument should be either a
[`string`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_string.htm) or a
[`function`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_fn.htm) (cf. the error message!)

You need to replace it with `(format stream "~S" text)` or just use [`prin1` or `write`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm).

Comment: In case in which i want do write into the output file JUST the elements of the list?
I mean, in my example the file foo.txt would contain (A B C), but is there a way to write only A B C without the parenthesys?

Comment: Either use iteration (e.g., or [`dolist`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dolist.htm)) or use [iteration in `format`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_cgd.htm).
If you have trouble with those, please ask a separate question.